# Is it possible to show loading everytime webview content is change in android studio?

Tags: android, webview

I have webview in my android where i display webpage.
here is the android code.

```
mWebview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings mWebviewSettings= mWebview.getSettings();
mWebviewSettings.setDefaultFontSize(17);
mWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, null, true, false);
mProgress.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
mProgress.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
// add a WebViewClient for WebView, which actually handles loading data from web
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    // load url
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!mProgress.isShowing()) {
            mProgress.show();
        }
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    // when finish loading page
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }
});

mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
// set url for webview to load
mWebview.loadUrl("https://urlname.com/pagename.php");
```

my question is, is it possible to show loading everytime webview content is change when i click link inside webview?

Comment: Override the `onPageStarted()` method and show your `ProgressDialog` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom webview client and in it you need to check page changes. It can be done with a `boolean` variable

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    boolean onPageStarted = false;
    Runnable hideLoadingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!onPageStarted ) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        onPageStarted = true;
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        onPageStarted = false;            
        yourwebview.postDelayed(hideLoadingRunnable, 1000);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE** based on comment

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {


    WebView mWebview;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.youractivitylayout);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.yourprogress);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        boolean onPageStarted = false;
        Runnable hideLoadingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!onPageStarted) {
                    mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            onPageStarted = true;
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            onPageStarted = false;
            yourwebview.postDelayed(hideLoadingRunnable, 1000);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the runnable used for if url is redirecting to another url.

Comment: hi thank you for the answer.. sorry im new in android.. can you help me to construct my code to apply this custom webview.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use webview  `setWebChromeClient()`

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        //start progressbar here
        if (!mProgress.isShowing()) {
            mProgress.show();
        }
        view.loadUrl(url);
        //stopprogressbar here
        if (progress == 100) {
            if (mProgress.isShowing()) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
});
```